# Can we predict correlation between independent variables based on dependent variables

Tags: statistics, correlation, linear-regression

I have a correlation matrix for dependent var Vs independent variable as below:

Year   1       Sales
Sales -0.5453  1.0000
PriceIndex    -0.6089 
Income        -0.5033 
Interest      -0.3842

As we can see that all independent var have negative correlation with the dependent variable. However as one of the requirement that i have for my project is that based on these values can i predict correlation between my independent variables.

Kindly suggest if we can predict the same.
Thanks, Shivi

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick analysis of your situation:

1. **[Correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) among Independent Variables:** The [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) between independent variables (PriceIndex, Income, and Interest) is not explicitly provided in your data. To determine the [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) between these independent variables, you would need to calculate their correlation coefficients separately. This can be done using the same method you used for the [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) between Sales and the independent variables.
2. **Prediction of [Correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) among Independent Variables:** It's important to note that the [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) between independent variables ([multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity)) is distinct from their relationship with the dependent variable. The correlation between independent variables indicates whether they are linearly related to each other. You can predict or calculate this correlation by performing a [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) analysis between the independent variables themselves.

Here's how you can proceed:

1. Calculate the correlation coefficients between each pair of independent variables (PriceIndex, Income, and Interest).
2. Analyze the results to understand if there is a significant linear relationship between the independent variables.
3. If the correlation between independent variables is substantial, it suggests [multicollinearity](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/multicollinearity), which can affect regression analysis. In such cases, you may need to consider techniques like [Principal Component Analysis](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/principal-component-analysis-en) (PCA) or Variable Selection to address multicollinearity.